# DHCP Multiple IP address request

Tags: networking, udp, router, dhcp

I am trying to mimic a DHCP client from my end using C++ Code. My objective is to get some free/unused IP's from the DHCP server to assign it to different equipments - similar to a DHCP Relay, but not technically the same. My `CLIENT` is running on an Embedded linux platform and talks to a DHCP server via our internal network.

As per the DHCP protocol there is a formal procedure (`DISCOVER`, `OFFER`, `REQUEST`, `ACK/NAK`, `RELEASE`) to communicate with the DHCP server.According to the RFC's(2131), when I do a `DISCOVER`, I receive and `OFFER` with an unused IP address in the YIAddr field. I further use this IP address in my `REQUEST` message using option 50 as mentioned in RFC 2132.

My main router, make- Edgewater(which is also the DHCP server) on sending a `DISCOVER` message, sends back an `OFFER` message with an unused IP address in the YIAddr field (I used this unused IP in my consequent `REQUEST` message), which is my requirement. I did the same experiment with few other router's (NetGear, Dlink, Broadcom) and found that the `OFFER` message is sending me back the same IP address of the `CLIENT` that is requesting the unused IP's. I am curious to know why this is happening. As I understand, I'm following the steps mentioned in RFC2131/RFC2131/RFC4361 for creating my DHCP packet format.

Is there a specific format or specific option that the other DHCP server/Routers are expecting to give out unused IP's? I am using a unique client identifier in my option field as mentioned in RFC4361.

This is a snap shot of the section where I'm creating the dhcp packet.

```
    request_packet.m_OperationCode  =   0x01;
request_packet.m_HwareType  =   0x01;
request_packet.m_HwareLen   =   0x06;
request_packet.m_Hops       =   0x01;
request_packet.m_XID        =   htonl(XID[m_numberOfIPs]);
request_packet.m_Secs       =   htons(0x10);
request_packet.m_flags      =   htons(0x8000);
request_packet.m_CIAddr     =   0x000000; //Client IP
request_packet.m_YIAddr     =   0x000000; //Your IP
request_packet.m_SIAddr     =   0x000000; //Server IP
request_packet.m_GIAddr         =   0x000000;
request_packet.m_CHAddr[0]  =   MACADDRESS[m_numberOfIPs][0];
request_packet.m_CHAddr[1]  =   MACADDRESS[m_numberOfIPs][1];//[1];
request_packet.m_CHAddr[2]  =   MACADDRESS[m_numberOfIPs][2];//[2];
request_packet.m_CHAddr[3]  =   MACADDRESS[m_numberOfIPs][3];//[3];
request_packet.m_CHAddr[4]  =   MACADDRESS[m_numberOfIPs][4];//[4];
request_packet.m_CHAddr[5]  =   MACADDRESS[m_numberOfIPs][5];//[5];
memset(request_packet.m_CHAddr+6, 0, 10);
memset(request_packet.m_SName, 0, 64);      
memset(request_packet.m_File, 0, 128);  
request_packet.m_pOptions[0]    =   99; //Start of magic cookie
request_packet.m_pOptions[1]    =   130;            
request_packet.m_pOptions[2]    =   83;
request_packet.m_pOptions[3]    =   99; //end of magic cookie
```

## Options Field

### DISCOVER message

CID and DUID are random unique numbers to create a unique client identifier

```
 request_packet.m_pOptions[4]   =   53; //DHCP MESSAGE TYPE OPTION CODE
 request_packet.m_pOptions[5]   =   1;  //OPTION DATA LEN
 request_packet.m_pOptions[6]   =   1;  //DHCP DISCOVER

 request_packet.m_pOptions[7]   =   55; //Parameter Request List
 request_packet.m_pOptions[8]   =   7; //Length
 request_packet.m_pOptions[9]   =   1; //Subnet Mask
 request_packet.m_pOptions[10]  =   3; //Router
 request_packet.m_pOptions[11]  =   6; //Domain Name Server
 request_packet.m_pOptions[12]  =   12; // Host Name
 request_packet.m_pOptions[13]  =   15; //Domain Name
 request_packet.m_pOptions[14]  =   28; //Broadcast Address
 request_packet.m_pOptions[15]  =   42; //NTP servers

 request_packet.m_pOptions[16]  =   51; //IP Address Lease Time
 request_packet.m_pOptions[17]  =   4;  
 request_packet.m_pOptions[18]  =   0x00;
 request_packet.m_pOptions[19]  =   0x00;
 request_packet.m_pOptions[20]  =   0xFF;
 request_packet.m_pOptions[21]  =   0xFF;

 request_packet.m_pOptions[22]  =   61;//Client Identifier code
 request_packet.m_pOptions[23]  =   15;//Length
 request_packet.m_pOptions[24]  =   255;//IAID Type
 printf("The CID generated inside REQUEST is %x\n", CID[m_numberOfIPs]);
 request_packet.m_pOptions[25]  =   CID[m_numberOfIPs][0];
 request_packet.m_pOptions[26]  =   CID[m_numberOfIPs][1];
 request_packet.m_pOptions[27]  =   CID[m_numberOfIPs][2];
 request_packet.m_pOptions[28]  =   CID[m_numberOfIPs][3];
 request_packet.m_pOptions[29]  =   0x00;//DUID Type
 request_packet.m_pOptions[30]  =   0x03;//DUID Type
 request_packet.m_pOptions[31]  =   0x00;//HW Type code - Ethernet
 request_packet.m_pOptions[32]  =   0x01;//HW Type code - Ethernet
 request_packet.m_pOptions[33]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][0];
 request_packet.m_pOptions[34]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][1];
 request_packet.m_pOptions[35]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][2];
 request_packet.m_pOptions[36]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][3];
 request_packet.m_pOptions[37]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][4];
 request_packet.m_pOptions[38]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][5];


 request_packet.m_pOptions[39]  =   (0xff);  // End option
```

### REQUEST message

```
request_packet.m_pOptions[4]    =   53; //DHCP MESSAGE TYPE OPTION CODE
request_packet.m_pOptions[5]    =   1;  //OPTION DATA LEN
request_packet.m_pOptions[6]    =   3;  //DHCP REQUEST

request_packet.m_pOptions[7]    =   50; //DHCP REQUESTION OPTION
request_packet.m_pOptions[8]    =   4;  //OPTION DATA LEN
request_packet.m_pOptions[9]    =   (m_YourIP & 0xff000000)>>24;  //first byte
request_packet.m_pOptions[10]   =   (m_YourIP & 0xff0000)>>16;  //second byte
request_packet.m_pOptions[11]   =   (m_YourIP & 0xff00)>>8;  //third byte
request_packet.m_pOptions[12]   =   (m_YourIP & 0xff);  //fourth byte
/*- Added by JA. Refer 3.1.3 Section of RFC2131.txt - Server identifier option*/
 request_packet.m_pOptions[13]  =   54;
 request_packet.m_pOptions[14]   =  4;
 request_packet.m_pOptions[15]  =   (m_ServerIP & 0xff000000) >> 24; //first byte
 request_packet.m_pOptions[16]  =   (m_ServerIP & 0xff0000)>>16;  //second byte
 request_packet.m_pOptions[17]  =   (m_ServerIP & 0xff00)>>8;  //third byte
 request_packet.m_pOptions[18]  =   (m_ServerIP & 0xff);  //fourth byte

 request_packet.m_pOptions[19]  =   55; //Parameter Request List
 request_packet.m_pOptions[20]  =   7; //Length
 request_packet.m_pOptions[21]  =   1; //Subnet Mask
 request_packet.m_pOptions[22]  =   3; //Router
 request_packet.m_pOptions[23]  =   6; //Domain Name Server
 request_packet.m_pOptions[24]  =   12; // Host Name
 request_packet.m_pOptions[25]  =   15; //Domain Name
 request_packet.m_pOptions[26]  =   28; //Broadcast Address
 request_packet.m_pOptions[27]  =   42; //NTP servers

     request_packet.m_pOptions[28]  =   51; //IP Address Lease Time
     request_packet.m_pOptions[29]  =   4;  
     request_packet.m_pOptions[30]  =   0x00;
     request_packet.m_pOptions[31]  =   0x00;
     request_packet.m_pOptions[32]  =   0xFF;
     request_packet.m_pOptions[33]  =   0xFF;

     /*- Added by JA. Refer 6.1 Section of RFC4361.txt - Client identifier option*/
     request_packet.m_pOptions[34]  =   61;//Client Identifier code
     request_packet.m_pOptions[35]  =   15;//Length
     request_packet.m_pOptions[36]  =   255;//IAID Type
     printf("The CID generated inside REQUEST is %x\n", CID[m_numberOfIPs]);
     request_packet.m_pOptions[37]  =   CID[m_numberOfIPs][0];
     request_packet.m_pOptions[38]  =   CID[m_numberOfIPs][1];
     request_packet.m_pOptions[39]  =   CID[m_numberOfIPs][2];
     request_packet.m_pOptions[40]  =   CID[m_numberOfIPs][3];
     request_packet.m_pOptions[41]  =   0x00;//DUID Type
     request_packet.m_pOptions[42]  =   0x03;//DUID Type
     request_packet.m_pOptions[43]  =   0x00;//HW Type code - Ethernet
     request_packet.m_pOptions[44]  =   0x01;//HW Type code - Ethernet
     request_packet.m_pOptions[45]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][0];
     request_packet.m_pOptions[46]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][1];
     request_packet.m_pOptions[47]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][2];
     request_packet.m_pOptions[48]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][3];
     request_packet.m_pOptions[49]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][4];
     request_packet.m_pOptions[50]  =   DUID[m_numberOfIPs][5];
     request_packet.m_pOptions[51]  =   (0xff);  // End option
```

Comment: I'm calling this function (which creates the packet) 'x' times depending on the number of free IP's I require. Now on giving a unique MAC address field in the m_ChAddr field for each DORA(Discover-Offer-Request-ACK) I am getting an unused IP address back in the m_YIAddr field which is what I need. From reading the rfc's I thought by keeping the MAC address the same and giving a unique client identifier for each DORA, it should have worked (and it is working with our main router - Edgewater). Do some routers expect a unique MAC address to be provided in each DORA to release an unused IP?

Answer (score 0):

Using router as DHCP relay and server it will assign you Unique IP based DHCP subnetwork configured on it say 10.1.2.0/24 is the pool defined on router for DHCP requests it will assign you very first non-allocated IP against your MAC only and this assignment is random you can not reserve mac on router.After DORA it triggers lease timer for that MAC-IP .

If you use DHCP server Microsoft/Unix they they have extended functionality as reserving IP for particular mac permanently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand an IP is allocated against a MAC addresses. I'm trying to figure out if the protocol/RFC's support a DHCP client to get different unique unallocated IP with the same MAC addresses( mac address of the DHCP client).

Comment: router does not reserves ip for perticular mac permanently ; its possible to get unique ip via dhcp relay each time dhcp client queries.

Comment: My dhcp client is in the same subnet as that of the dhcp server. I do not want to reserve IP for a mac permanently. I want the dhcp client to get some IP addresses(sort of like a relay agent, but not fully) based on it's MAC address and pass these IP's to various devices(these devices do not have MAC addresses)